# DolphinDB: How to group a table by a certain column and calculate the correlation of columns in each group?

Tags: group-by, correlation, dolphindb

I want to group a table by column “z“ and calculate the correlation of column “x“ with columns “y1“, “y2“… in each group using the script `corr:R(table.x. table[y1y2...]`. How to achieve this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `groups` function to group the table by column "z", which returns a tuple whose elements are the indices of each unique value in column “z“. Use the script `t @ groups(t.z, 'tuple')` to return tables representing the records of each group and use the `corr` function to calculate the correlation of columns "y1", "y2", and "y3" in each group, as shown in the following script:

```
t = table(1..10 as x, 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 as z, rand(1.0, 10) as y1, rand(1.0, 10) as y2, rand(1.0,10) as y3)
each(f->corr:R(f.x, f[`y1`y2`y3]), t @ groups(t.z, 'tuple'))
```